# Batch exporting groups of 100 polygons from shapefile into new layers using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, batch, split-by-attribute

I have a shapefile of about 14,000 overlapping polygons that I need to separate into layers of 100 for processing purposes.

Is there a way to create these layers without manually selecting each group of 100?

Answer (score 3):

To do this I would:

1. Add an empty field ready hold a group ID for each group of 100
2. Calculate that field to hold a group ID for each group of 100.  Using ranges of Object IDs would be one way to perform the grouping.
3. Use [Split By Attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm) which:

> Splits an input dataset by unique attributes.

---

As commented by @MichaelStimson:

> The python field calculator expression **int(!FID!/100)** would be one
> way to group into the hundreds, where FID is the OID field in a
> geodatabase.